# Переклад з польської міст Rzeszów та Przemyśl

Tags: переклад, власні-назви

Хотілося б дізнатися як правильніше перекладати географічні назви з польської. Два основні питання це стосовно міст Rzeszów та Przemyśl.

Правильним перекладом Rzeszów вважають Ряшів, аргументуючи це тим, що це традиційний український варіант (або відповідник). Але так як це місто у Польщі, більш правильним, мені здається, транслітерація з польської на українську — Жешув.

Та сама ситуація з містом Przemyśl. Перемишль або Пшемисль?

Дякую!

Comment: «Правопис» 2015, як не дивно, у прикладах наводить [Пере́мишль](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par113p2vprym) та [Же́шув](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par109p7g).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я вже збирався сказати, мовляв, «така вже наша традиція, яка б вона не була (хороша чи погана), називати ці міста саме *Перемишль* і *Ряшів*; Ви, звісно, можете спробувати зламати традицію, однак наразі „нормативнішими“ назвами є саме *Перемишль* і *Ряшів*, і жодні словники не подадуть Вам *Пшемисль* чи *Жешув*» — однак зазирнув у словник/газетир, і здається, ситуація майже зворотня:

- [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) від УМІФ (2008) подають не лише *Перемишль* та *Ряшів*, а й також *Пшемисль* та *Жешув* як нормативні варіанти:

  > **Пше́мисль** — іменник чоловічого роду *(місто в Польщі)*
  >    **Же́шув** — іменник чоловічого роду *(місто в Польщі)*
  >     **Пере́мишль** – іменник чоловічого роду *(укр. назва міста Пшемисль в Польщі)*
  >     **Ря́шів** – іменник чоловічого роду *(українська назва м. Жешув, Польща)*

  Причому в коментарях до назв *Перемишль* та *Ряшів* словник посилається до назв *Пшемисль* та *Жешув* (як до основних?).
- [«Газетир (покажчик) географічних назв світу»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Minekoresursiv_Ukrainy/Hazetyr_pokazhchyk_heohrafichnykh_nazv_svitu/) від Укркартографії (2005; раніше був розміщений прямо [на сайті Укркартографії](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911024801/http://ukrmap.com.ua:80/services/kodeksi-ustalenoji-praktiki/), але з часом його звідти прибрали) подає лише *Пшемишль* та *Жешув*, але не *Перемишль* чи *Ряшів*:

  > Назва українською | Назва національною або латинкою | Рід об'єкта | Країна
  >   ———————————————————
  >   [Жешув](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Minekoresursiv_Ukrainy/Hazetyr_pokazhchyk_heohrafichnykh_nazv_svitu.pdf#page=635) | Rzeszów | нас. пункт | Польща
  >   [Пшемишль](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Minekoresursiv_Ukrainy/Hazetyr_pokazhchyk_heohrafichnykh_nazv_svitu.pdf#page=1411) | Przemyśl | нас. пункт | Польща

  (Щоправда, газетир подає нас. пункт *Перемишль*, але країною для нього зазначена Росія, тож, імовірно, мається на увазі село Перемишль Калузької області в Росії.)

  Щоправда, написання назви *Пшемишль* газетирі Укркартографії відрізняється від поданого Вами й у словнику УМІФ (*Пшемисль*). Але оскільки газетир відомий своїми нестандартними написаннями (Браз*і*лія, Зел*ьо*ний *Ґ*ай тощо), що з'являються на географічних картах, але часто суперечать тому, що вживається в побуті, літературі й на офіційному рівні, то з варіантів *Пшемисль*/*Пшемишль* я особисто обираю *Пшемисль*.
- [«Правопис»](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm) (2015) згадує *Перемишль* і *Жешув*.

  *Перемишль* згадується в [примітці до § 113.2.в](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par113p2vprym):

  > Деякі слова, узвичаєні без зміни приголосних основ, передаються з ними і на письмі: *ба́ски* — *ба́скський*, *каза́х* — *каза́хський*, *Пере́мишль* — *пере́мишльський* та ін.

  (Щоправда, незрозуміло, про який Перемишль тут мова: місто в Польщі, село в Україні чи село в Росії. Примітка може навіть не стосується конкретного топоніма, суть її може бути в тому, що для будь-чого, що ми називаємо Перемишлем, нормативним прикметником буде *перемишльський*, а не *перемиський*.)

  *Жешув* згадується в [§ 109.7.ґ](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par109p7g):

  > Польське *ó*, що виступає в суфіксі *-ów* у географічних назвах, передається через *у*: *Жира́рдув*, *Же́шув*, *Тома́шув-Мазове́цький* і т. ін., але традиційно *Гру́бешів*, *Кра́ків*.

Отже припускаю, що всі 4 слова — *Перемишль*, *Пшемисль*, *Ряшів*, *Жешув* — є нормативними. Які сами використовувати — обирати Вам. При офіційному спілкуванні з поляками, звісно, рекомендую вживати *Пшемисль* і *Жешув*; у перекладах — в залежності від того, який колорит варто передати (в нейтральних текстах про сучасну Польщу — можливо, *Пшемисль* і *Жешув*).

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Повністю погоджуюсь з вашою аргументацією і, власне, коли перекладаю польські назви на українську користуюсь цією таблицею, яка в багатьому посилається на документ від Картографії (Інструкція з передачі українською мовою географічних назв і термінів Польщі. Міністерство екології та природних ресурсів України. 2001). Проте він, на жаль, недоступний нині. За ним, саме Пшемисль і Жешув — правильний переклад. Пишу інформаційні тексти про Польщу і тому часто необхідна аргументація чому так правильно і чому не лише Ряшів можна писати.

Answer (score 2):

Ось що пише [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D1%88%D1%96%D0%B2) про місто Ряшів чи Жешув:

> Ря́шів, польська назва Же́шув (пол. Rzeszów).
>
> У XIV ст. Перемишльська земля переходить під владу Польщі, тому зараз
>   у багатьох мовах офіційно використовується польська назва Rzeszów, що
>   залишалася в такій формі і під час перебування Перемишльської землі в
>   складі Австрійської імперії (1772—1918). **Серед українців місто
>   здавна відоме як «Ряшів»** (старе написання «Ряшевъ»), **навіть у
>   виданнях Російської імперії місто називалося Ряшевъ** (Вікіпедія дає посилання на книгу "Большая энциклопедия").

А також про це говориться в статті "[Ряшів - західний фортпост галицької Руси](https://zbruc.eu/node/70997)":

> Назва міста вживалася в історичних документах по-різному, тому в
>   латинській транскрипції слов’янське слово могло читатись довільно:
>   Rzazov, Rzissov, Rischov, Reschov, Ressovia, Rzeschow і т. д. Але
>   слово навіть в такому вигляді відбиває основні звуки української назви
>   Ряшів чи польської Жешув (Rzeszόw). Йосип Пеленський виводив саму
>   назву від німецького слова “Reichshof”, себто дворище якогось Райха.
>   Та це припущенння виглядає непереконливо. В українській топонімці
>   збереглися чимало прикладів подібних назв – таких, як Рашків,
>   Рашківці, Рашовичі тощо.

Тобто Ряшів - це українська назва міста, а Жешув - польська. Очевидно, що причина це історичні події, які відбувалися на Перемишльській землі в той час (а саме ополяченя всіх українців та українських міст). Хоч зараз багато українців кажуть Жешув (сайт [Мандрівні Мрії](http://traveldreams.com.ua/city/poland/rzeszow/)):

> В Україні Ряшів часто називають на польський штиб - Жешув.

Гадаю, що така сама ситуація і з містом Перемишль (а знаходиться воно знову ж таки на Перемишльській землі). Про це місто і його назву набагато менше інформації. Звичайно, є [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8C), де бачимо назву "Перемишль" та навіть "Перемешль". А от цікаво, що якщо зайти на російську [Вікіпедію](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8C#%D0%92%D0%BE_%D0%92%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5), то бачимо:

> Пше́мысль (польск. Przemyśl, [ˈpʂɛmɨɕl]) укр. Пере́мишль, в русском
>   языке в историческом контексте традиционно используется название
>   Перемышль)

Який же був історичний контекст? Як я вже писав - це процес ополячення чи [полонізації](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F). Навіть якщо ми глянемо на період коли почався цей процей і коли Перемишльська земля була приєднана до Королівства Польського, то можемо побачити одну і ту ж дату, 1434 рік.

Comment: додав би ще, що є коментар філолога на цю тему за посиланням https://shpalta.media/2020/03/02/misto-z-troma-nazvami-ale-pravilna-lishe-odna/

Answer (score 1):

Як видно, *Rzesz**ó**w* містить *ó* — в більшостӥ випадків, а тут саме такиь, цє етимолоґічне чергуваня *у* ~ *о* — цєбто при відмінюванї [стане](https://sjp.pl/Rzesz%C3%B3w) *Rzesz**o**wa*. Нагадує і по сутї є відповідником нашого *~ів*: *Ки**ї**в* – *Ки**є**ва* (котриь [*Kij**ó**w*](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kij%C3%B3w)), *Харк**і**в* – *Харк**о**ва*. Не складно здогадати ся, шчо польських міст з *~ów* вистачає, одним *Жешувом* [тут не обіьти ся](http://wiadomosci.gazeta.pl/wiadomosci/56,114944,16933671,Dlaczego_na_polnocy_jest_RedlOWO_i_MragOWO__a_na_poludniu.html), наприклад славнозвісне *Крак**і**в* стане [*Кракув*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2), котрого чомусь немаʼ, як [*Жеш**у**в*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%96%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%83%D0%B2) в, як приклад, згаданому Сашою *Словники Украӥни онлаьн*, шчо сутєво зменшує рівень, як на мене, арґументу самого словника. З цӧго також випливає можливиь і незгаданиь тут варіант [***Жешів***](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&safe=off&q="%D0%96%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%96%D0%B2") котрого теж подекуди вживають, причім не рідко — таке собі поєднанє польського корня з украӥнською словотворчиною.

Згадана «хвороба» правопису *невизначених виьняткових традиціь* не дуже допомагає рішеню, а навпаки. Навіть тут — *Ряшів* же є типовим традиціьним словом — не лиш’ для украӥнської: латиньська *Resovia*, чеська *Řešov*, жидівська רײַשע *(Rajsze)*, московська *Ряшев*. Отже, коли вживаємо (коли є згадана «хвороба») традиціьні написи чи пряму передачу слів? Лоґіка підказує, шчо цӧму за такими нормами є також політичні питаня, одне з котрих є згаданим паном Анатолієм — ополяченє, або же, я б сказав, відʼукраӥненє, бо більше нїхто не вживає саме *Ряшів*. Не скажу, шчо цє є чимось завше поганим, але цє залишаєть ся одним з факторів питаня вживу.